# JavaScript. Need to split name and surname and pass test below

Tags: javascript, arrays

everyone! I need to find errors in function, because test don't pass me. I'm starting to learn js, and this task is difficult to me. Thank you!

```
  first?: string;
  last?: string;
}

export class CleverUserConverters {
  static ParseUserName(name: ICleverName): Required<ICleverName> {
    let str1 = name.first?.split(' ');
    let str2 = name.last?.split(' ');

    return {
      first: str1[0],
      last: str2[0],
    };
  }
}


describe('AppController', () => {
  it('should parse first and last names correctly', () => {
    const name1: ICleverName = { first: '1', last: '2' };
    const name2: ICleverName = { first: '1 2' };
    const name3: ICleverName = { last: '1 2' };

    const parsedName1 = CleverUserConverters.ParseUserName(name1);
    const parsedName2 = CleverUserConverters.ParseUserName(name2);
    const parsedName3 = CleverUserConverters.ParseUserName(name3);

    expect(parsedName1.first).toEqual('1');
    expect(parsedName1.last).toEqual('2');
    expect(parsedName2.first).toEqual('1');
    expect(parsedName2.last).toEqual('2');
    expect(parsedName3.first).toEqual('1');
    expect(parsedName3.last).toEqual('2');
  });
});
```

Comment: `str1 = name.first?.split(' ');` where `str1` could be `undefined`, and Can't read property '0' of undefined, `undefined[0]` doesn't make any sense...